# How to crawl some comments of a specific web-site? (I met a challenge.)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am a beginner of crawling, and I faced a difficult problem while studying.

Anyway, I tried to crawl a comment in web-NEWS but I failed.

This is my code in python with selenium.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

url = 'https://www.etnews.com/20200228000119?mc=em_101_00001'

driver.get(url)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#list > div:nth-child(3) > div.reply-bottom > div.reply-content-wrapper > div.reply-content > p')))

    comment_list = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#list > div:nth-child(3) > div.reply-bottom > div.reply-content-wrapper > div.reply-content > p')
except:
    print('Timeout')

print(comment_list.text) 

driver.quit()
```

---

I think the chromedriver did not seem to have detected the css_selector because output message is always 'Timeout'.

I don't know why the comments in the web-site which is one of the ordinary web-sites (https://www.etnews.com/) could not be crwaled by selenium.

I want to know reason. Plz, give me a great help.

(ps. I know HTML, CSS a little BUT don't know Javascript well)

Comment: Which comments are you looking at?

Comment: in which element you get an exception,`element` or `comment_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are looking at has an iframe. The comments are inside it.

In order to collect comments, you'll need to switch to iframe first and then you'll be able to access the elements inside the iframe, in your case, a comment. I modified your script to do it, try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.etnews.com/20200228000119?mc=em_101_00001'

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Switch to iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='livere']"))
# Search for comment
comment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#list > div:nth-child(3) > div.reply-bottom > div.reply-content-wrapper > div.reply-content > p')
print(comment.text)

driver.quit()
```

I hope it helps, good luck!